# google maps V3 same lat lng from mysql query

Tags: maps

I use [PHP mysql](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=de) for my google map.
Two different marker will be show (green for ja (yes), orange for nein (no)). But when two "things" have same lat and long only one of them will be shown (for example: a man (ja) and a women (nein) lives in same house)
How can I get two markers? I don´t want both in same infowindow and no cluster.
First the php:

```
    $query = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
parseToXML($row['kennelname'] .'</a>" ';
  echo '<marker ';

if ($row['studlist'] == 'ja')  
{echo 'studlist=" " ';} else {echo 'studlist="Daten nicht geprüft!" ';} 

  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['dogname']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['studlist'] . '" ';
  echo ' />';

}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

and the js:

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  ja: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  nein: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.162014, 10.450573),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("testfemale_de_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");

          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var studlist = markers[i].getAttribute("studlist");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));


          var html = 
          "<a href='/dog.php?id=" + id + "'>" +  name + "</a>" +
          "<br/><img  src='/photo/" + id + "/" + id + ".jpg' height='70' width='' alt=''>" + 

          "<br />" +studlist

           ;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When to markers share the same location you will see only one. You can select which one to show using the zIndex property of the marker. For example:

```
marker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```